# matplotlib: inset axes for multiple boxplots

Tags: python, plot, matplotlib, zooming, boxplot

I have a few boxplots in matplotlib that I want to zoom in on a particular y-range ([0,0.1]) using [inset axes](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/users/overview.html). It is not clear to me from the [example](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/examples/inset_locator_demo2.py) in the documentation how I should do this for multiple boxplots on the same figure. I was trying to modify the code provided this example, but there was too much unnecessary complexity. My code is pretty simple:

```
# dataToPlot is a list of lists, containing some data. 
plt.figure()
plt.boxplot(dataToPlot)
plt.savefig( 'image.jpeg', bbox_inches=0)
```

How do I add inset axes and zoom in on the first boxplot of the two? How can I do it for both?

EDIT: I tried the code below, but here's what I got:
[image]

What went wrong?

```
# what's the meaning of these two parameters?
fig = plt.figure(1, [5,4])
# what does 111 mean?
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.boxplot(data)
# ax.set_xlim(0,21)  # done automatically based on the no. of samples, right?
# ax.set_ylim(0,300) # done automatically based on max value in my samples, right?
# Create the zoomed axes
axins = zoomed_inset_axes(ax, 6, loc=1) # zoom = 6, location = 1 (upper right)
axins.boxplot(data)
# sub region of the original image
#here I am selecting the first boxplot by choosing appropriate values for x1 and x2 
# on the y-axis, I'm selecting the range which I want to zoom in, right?
x1, x2, y1, y2 = 0.9, 1.1, 0.0, 0.01
axins.set_xlim(x1, x2)
axins.set_ylim(y1, y2)
# even though it's false, I still see all numbers on both axes, how do I remove them?
plt.xticks(visible=False)
plt.yticks(visible=False)
# draw a bbox of the region of the inset axes in the parent axes and
# connecting lines between the bbox and the inset axes area
# what are fc and ec here? where do loc1 and loc2 come from?
mark_inset(ax, axins, loc1=2, loc2=4, fc="none", ec="0.5")
plt.savefig( 'img.jpeg', bbox_inches=0)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean by "multiple boxplots on the same figure". Do you have multiple subplots?

Comment: No, `dataToPlot` contains more than one sample of data, and `plt.boxplot` treats it as such: it draws as many boxplots as there are samples in its input.

Comment: So, can't you just do another
`axins=zoomed_inset_axes(ax,6,loc=2)`

and set different coordinate range for this next plot?

Comment: I'm not setting the position of each boxplot, so I don't know where they will appear exactly. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe I don't exactly know what your question is... do you want to set the range of the zoom plots automatically, rather than explicitly typing the yrange?

Comment: Also, `imshow` is for an image plot. Is that really what you want?

Comment: Ok, sorry. I wanted to add a box for each boxplot with a zoomed-in view on a specific y-axis range. I thought I could do this with inset axes. Can I?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15725/discussion-between-samb8s-and-ricky-robinson)

Comment: fc is something like "foreground color". For example, setting it to "k" will make the box which shows the zoomed area in the original plot totally black - not very useful :) Setting it to "none" makes it transparent so that the original data are still visible.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `loc` determines the location of the zoomed axis, 1 for `upper right`, 2 for `upper left` and so on. I modified the example code slightly to generate multiple zoomed axis.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import zoomed_inset_axes
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import mark_inset

import numpy as np

def get_demo_image():
    from matplotlib.cbook import get_sample_data
    import numpy as np
    f = get_sample_data("axes_grid/bivariate_normal.npy", asfileobj=False)
    z = np.load(f)
    # z is a numpy array of 15x15
    return z, (-3,4,-4,3)


fig = plt.figure(1, [5,4])
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

# prepare the demo image
Z, extent = get_demo_image()
Z2 = np.zeros([150, 150], dtype="d")
ny, nx = Z.shape
Z2[30:30+ny, 30:30+nx] = Z

# extent = [-3, 4, -4, 3]
ax.imshow(Z2, extent=extent, interpolation="nearest",
          origin="lower")

axins = zoomed_inset_axes(ax, 6, loc=1) # zoom = 6
axins.imshow(Z2, extent=extent, interpolation="nearest",
             origin="lower")

# sub region of the original image
x1, x2, y1, y2 = -1.5, -0.9, -2.5, -1.9
axins.set_xlim(x1, x2)
axins.set_ylim(y1, y2)

axins1 = zoomed_inset_axes(ax, 8, loc=2) # zoom = 8
axins1.imshow(Z2, extent=extent, interpolation="nearest",
             origin="lower")

# sub region of the original image
x1, x2, y1, y2 = -1.2, -0.9, -2.2, -1.9
axins1.set_xlim(x1, x2)
axins1.set_ylim(y1, y2)

plt.xticks(visible=False)
plt.yticks(visible=False)

# draw a bbox of the region of the inset axes in the parent axes and
# connecting lines between the bbox and the inset axes area
mark_inset(ax, axins, loc1=2, loc2=4, fc="none", ec="0.5")
mark_inset(ax, axins1, loc1=2, loc2=4, fc="none", ec="0.5")

plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

[image]

**Edit1:**

Similarly, you can also add zoomed axis in a boxplot. Here is an example

```
from pylab import *
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import zoomed_inset_axes
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import mark_inset

# fake up some data
spread = rand(50) * 100 
center = ones(25) * 50
flier_high = rand(10) * 100 + 100
flier_low = rand(10) * -100
data = concatenate((spread, center, flier_high, flier_low), 0)

# fake up some more data
spread= rand(50) * 100
center = ones(25) * 40
flier_high = rand(10) * 100 + 100
flier_low = rand(10) * -100
d2 = concatenate( (spread, center, flier_high, flier_low), 0 )
data.shape = (-1, 1)
d2.shape = (-1, 1)
data = [data, d2, d2[::2,0]]

# multiple box plots on one figure
fig = plt.figure(1, [5,4])
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.boxplot(data)
ax.set_xlim(0.5,5)
ax.set_ylim(0,300)

# Create the zoomed axes
axins = zoomed_inset_axes(ax, 3, loc=1) # zoom = 3, location = 1 (upper right)
axins.boxplot(data)

# sub region of the original image
x1, x2, y1, y2 = 0.9, 1.1, 125, 175
axins.set_xlim(x1, x2)
axins.set_ylim(y1, y2)
plt.xticks(visible=False)
plt.yticks(visible=False)

# draw bboxes of the two regions of the inset axes in the parent axes and
# connect lines between the bbox and the inset axes area
mark_inset(ax, axins, loc1=2, loc2=4, fc="none", ec="0.5")

show()
```

[image]

**Edit2**

In case the distribution is heterogeneous, i.e., most values are small with few very large values, the above zooming procedure might not work, as it will zoom both the `x` as well as `y` axis. In that case, it is better to change the scale of `y-axis` to `log`.

```
from pylab import *

# fake up some data
spread = rand(50) * 1
center = ones(25) * .5
flier_high = rand(10) * 100 + 100
flier_low = rand(10) * -100
data = concatenate((spread, center, flier_high, flier_low), 0)

# fake up some more data
spread = rand(50) * 1
center = ones(25) * .4
flier_high = rand(10) * 100 + 100
flier_low = rand(10) * -100
d2 = concatenate( (spread, center, flier_high, flier_low), 0 )
data.shape = (-1, 1)
d2.shape = (-1, 1)
data = [data, d2, d2[::2,0]]

# multiple box plots on one figure
fig = plt.figure(1, [5,4]) # Figure Size
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)  # Only 1 subplot 
ax.boxplot(data)
ax.set_xlim(0.5,5)
ax.set_ylim(.1,300)
ax.set_yscale('log')

show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. The documentation on this is still too complex for my purposes. I edited my original post to stress what I'm doing right now and removed all the unnecessary lines from the online example. Could you please modify my code, so I can see what I should actually do? Thanks.

Comment: Check the edited answer. If you have difficulty in understanding any specific part of the code, do let me know.

Comment: Thank you. I edited my post and added the output of your code and questions on some of the parameters used.

Comment: You put `y1, y2 = 0.0, 0.01` and `zoom = 6`. This means that in your zoomed y-axis is 0.06 which is still much smaller than [0-250] range in the main axis. You either have to increase the zoom or the y1, y2 value.

Comment: OK, thanks. It doesn't seem to be working as I expected. I wanted to show where the median is, that is, I wanted to show the range where the blue rectangle lies, but when I zoom in too much, it also zooms in on the x-axis and it is a bit of a mess.

Comment: You can also change `x1, x2` to fix the zoomed x-axis. It seems that most of your data values are much small. In this case you can try setting the y-axis to log by using `ax.set_ylabel('log')`.Regarding other questions in your code, it is best to use help, e.g., `help plt.figure` to find out the more about the function.

Comment: Yes, I tried with `x1,x2=0.999999,1.000001`, but it didn't help much. Well, I guess there isn't much else I can do at this point. I'll try with log. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much for your last edit. Now my graphs are definitely more meaningful.